# Time element in WordPress site not in format required by HTML5

Tags: wordpress, html5, date-format

I'm trying to display blog posts using the BlogPosting schema, but I am having difficulty getting the date to display in an acceptable format.

Currently, the `responsive_child_post_meta_data()` function contains the following:

```
<time itemprop="datePublished">%2$s</time>
```

But when I try to validate the results using the W3C HTML Validator, I get the following error message:

> Error: The text content of element `time` was not in the required format: The literal did not satisfy the time-datetime format. Syntax of time-datetime: One of the following: month, date, yearless date, time, local date and time, time-zone offset, global date and time, week, non-negative integer, or duration. For more information and examples, see the section on the datetime value in the HTML specification.

Comment: Fix your php variable at `%2$s`

Comment: You're right... that's what needed to be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the date format in the Wordpress dashboard (Settings > General) to YYYY-MM-DD